# Danny Ocean using Guns

Tags: oceans-eleven

I recently re-watched Oceans Eleven today, and one scene I don't fully understand is when Ocean and Rusty are in a diner at the beginning talking. The exchange goes like this:

> Danny: It's tricky.  No one's ever done it before.  Needs planning, a
>   large crew.
>
> Rusty: Guns?
>
> Danny: Not loaded ones.  It has to be very precise.  There's a lot of
>   security.  But the take...

When they mention guns are they talking literal guns, or do they mean something else? To me it seems kind of strange for Danny to use guns. In the beginning when he is being interviewed to determine if he gets paroled, I don't recall anyone saying anything about murder, attempting to kill anyone.

Comment: Are there different versions of this movie? I'm watching it now and the dialogue isn't what you quoted. Rusty says "Guns?", to which Danny says "Not exactly. High security, but the take...". Most importantly, **Danny never references "unloaded guns"** (which is good IMO, because that would give too much away)

Comment: @LevenTrek - I took this quote from a script I found online. It may not have been the final draft version, I do recall the references to guns and wondered what that meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of 'Guns' is referring to who they are choosing for their crew to pull off the heist, in particular what the skill sets of their potential gang members will be.

Just because Danny typically sues guile and misdirection to complete his jobs, doesn't mean all his bank robberies are planned this way. There will no doubt be some more violent heists in Danny and Rusty's past, albeit it not being the way they choose to do things.

When Rusty asks 'Guns?', the inference of his question is 'will we be taking the place by force?' i.e using weapons (or personnel who are weapons effective, likely mercenaries).

Danny's answer of 'not loaded ones' is both a clever narrative foreshadowing of the final act, and a statement that they men they will use will not be dangerous or violent by nature.

Answer (score 10):

As I recall it there is a shootout between the men in the vault and the SWAT team - which we later find out are both Ocean's men. So the shootout is fake probably using fake guns. The conversation you are referring to, is probably about this. So he means they will use guns but only for show / deception, not to shoot some one.